# Directories as wildcards when using checkpoints

Tags: python, snakemake

I have tried to use subdirectories as wildcards, but `snakemake` expands the wildcards into the subdirectories. I have tried to come up with a minimal example, but it was not easy to do so. Apologies if the example isn't all that clear. It should work out of the box though.

**Explanation of Pipeline**

`rule firststep`: This rule basically creates the two folders for wildcards `runs`

```
runs = ['run1', 'run2']

rule firststep:
    output:
        '{run}/firststep_done.txt'
    shell:
        'touch {output} ;'
```

`checkpoint secondstep`: This rule will output an arbitrary number of subdirectories, which will later be used as `wildcards` (`projectA` & `projectB`). Inside the subdirectories, an arbitrary number of files are generated.

```
checkpoint secondstep:
    input:
        '{run}/firststep_done.txt',
    output:
        DIR = directory('{run}/secondstep')
    shell:
        'mkdir -p {output.DIR} ;'
        'mkdir -p {wildcards.run}/secondstep/projectA ;'
        'touch {wildcards.run}/secondstep/projectA/file_arbitrary.1 ;'
        'touch {wildcards.run}/secondstep/projectA/file_arbitrary.2 ;'
        'mkdir -p {wildcards.run}/secondstep/projectB ;'
        'touch {wildcards.run}/secondstep/projectB/file_arbitrary.1 ;'
        'touch {wildcards.run}/secondstep/projectB/file_arbitrary.2 ;'
```

`rule intermediate`: This rule uses the new wildcard `projects` to create a file in a different directory where the subdirectory is the `projects` wildcard.

```
rule intermediate:
    input:
        directory('{run}/secondstep/{project}')
    output:
        '{run}/report/{project}/arbitrary.all'
    shell:
        'echo "foo" > {output}'
```

As a next step, I create an input function for an aggregation rule:

```
def resolve_project(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output=checkpoints.secondstep.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    return expand('{run}/report/{project}/arbitrary.all',
                  run=wildcards.run,
                  project=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output,
                                                 "{project}")).project)
```

Then, the last rule `aggregate` uses the inputs created by the function to finish the pipeline:

```
rule aggregate:
    input:
        resolve_project
    output:
        '{run}/report/{run}_done'
    shell:
        'cat {input} > {output}'
```

I post the complete pipeline for copy-pasting below.

I see two problems:

1. The wildcards for `rule intermediate` are e.g.:

`wildcards: run=run1, project=projectB/file_arbitrary.2`.

But I would like the wildcard `{project}` to be only `projectA` or `projectB`. How can I achieve this?

2. Since snakemake creates a `.snakemake_timestamp` in the folder `secondstep`, I also have a wildcard called `.snakemake_timestamp`. How can I tell snakemake to only infer wildcards from directories?

Any help is appreciated.

Complete pipeline:

```
runs = ['run1', 'run2']

rule all:
    input:
        expand('{run}/report/{run}_done', run = runs)

rule firststep:
    output:
        '{run}/firststep_done.txt'
    shell:
        'touch {output} ;'


checkpoint secondstep:
    input:
        '{run}/firststep_done.txt',
    output:
        DIR = directory('{run}/secondstep')
    shell:
        'mkdir -p {output.DIR} ;'
        'mkdir -p {wildcards.run}/secondstep/projectA ;'
        'touch {wildcards.run}/secondstep/projectA/file_arbitrary.1 ;'
        'touch {wildcards.run}/secondstep/projectA/file_arbitrary.2 ;'
        'mkdir -p {wildcards.run}/secondstep/projectB ;'
        'touch {wildcards.run}/secondstep/projectB/file_arbitrary.1 ;'
        'touch {wildcards.run}/secondstep/projectB/file_arbitrary.2 ;'

rule intermediate:
    input:
        directory('{run}/secondstep/{project}')
    output:
        '{run}/report/{project}/arbitrary.all'
    shell:
        'echo "blabla" > {output}'


def resolve_project(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output=checkpoints.secondstep.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    return expand('{run}/report/{project}/arbitrary.all',
                  run=wildcards.run,
                  project=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output,
                                                 "{project}")).project)

rule aggregate:
    input:
        resolve_project
    output:
        '{run}/report/{run}_done'
    shell:
        'cat {input} > {output}'
```

**Edit**

As pointed out in the below answer, it is a problem of the wildcard constraint. However, it didn't work to do a global wildcard constraint. Since there is an input function at play, the constraint has to be defined in the `glob_wildcards` statement:

```
def resolve_project(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output=checkpoints.secondstep.get(**wildcards).output[0]
    return expand('{run}/report/{project}/arbitrary.all',
                  run=wildcards.run,
                  project=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output,
                                                 "{project, [^/|^.]+}")).project)
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `wildcard_constraints`: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/additional_features.html#constraining-wildcards

That allows you to define a regular expression that would limit your wildcard to whatever you define using a regular expression. For example:

```py
wildcard_constraints:
    project="[^/]+"
```

There are several ways to define the constraint: globally, for a rule or inline. Here is an example of inline constraint: `output: '{run}/report/{project,[^/]+}/arbitrary.all'`.

Comment: Thanks. I assumed that it must be done with wildcard constraints. However, your solution doesn't work (neither the globally defined constraint, nor the inline constraint). Could you post a working example?

Comment: That is not "my solution" but your solution that doesn't work. I've just answered your queston as you had asked: how to force `{project}` to be only projectA or projectB. Whenever you provide a minimal example, I would provide a minimal working example (if the only problem in your code would be in the wildcard constraints).

Comment: The minimal example should work out of the box without an error (at least for me it did - see the code at the end of the post).  That's why I asked for a working example.

Comment: I now managed to get it to work (see edit). The problem was that the global wildcard constraint doesn't work, most likely because of the use of an input function. If I specify the constraint in the input function, it works as expected. Thanks for your help.